# Unable to Update partitions in kafka using Sarama Library

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

I have tried to use the Sarama Go library to update the partitions in kafka, Can anybody suggest whether this library support this feature?

```
func UpdateTopic_part(topicDetails *TopicInfo, con kafka.ClusterAdmin) {
    fmt.Println("update Partitions")
    topicAssignment := make([][]int32, 0, 2)

    err := con.AlterPartitionReassignments(topicDetails.Topic_name, topicAssignment)

    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: All you've done here is make an empty 2D slice. You need to populate it with broker IDs and partition values first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`CreatePartitions`](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/main/admin.go#L43) if you want to "update partitions" (note: partitions cannot be reduced in Kafka) of an existing topic.

`AlterPartitionReassignments` is primarily to be used for moving existing partitions around, the same as `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh`. That 2d array is a list of brokerIds, each to a list of partitions that each broker would store.

Comment: It would be great to have an example of AlterPartitionReassignments on this answer, since this is what I was looking for when I found this question.

Comment: It accepts the same arguments as `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh`